# Can I use patternfilterfactory to remove the string "THE " of the field I'm importing into Solr

Tags: solr, solr4

For the phrase like "THE QUICK BROWN FOX", I want to remove the word "THE " at the beginning so that it will appear as "QUICK BROWN FOX".

I've tried the following settings in schema.xml and none have worked. What ends up happening is it removes the word "THE" even if it's not found at the beginning of the phrase.

i.e. "QUICK AND THE DEAD" turns into "QUICK AND DEAD"

"solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(the )" replacement="" replace="all"/>

"solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(the\s)" replacement="" replace="all"/>

"solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(the\s)" replacement="" replace="all"/>

I'm using KeywordTokenizerFactory because I'm doing an exact match.

The goal is if I send the following phrase to Solr for indexing,

"THE QUICK BROWN FOX", it will drop the word "THE" at the beginning of the phrase only and transform in solr into "QUICK BROWN FOX".

Any Ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: While you're at it, you may also want to exclude the other articles, "a" and "an".

Comment: Yup. The users wanted that to, along with LA and EL

Answer (score 2):

The `pattern` value is a regular expression, and as you *only* want to remove leading “The“, you should anchor it at the beginning using `^`:

```
pattern="^the\s+"
```

Comment: Thank you. i tried this "the quick and the dead" in solr analysis and it is now being shown as "quick and the dead".

Answer (score 0):

> in addition to BlueM's answer

```
check that you have not used solr.StopFilterFactory and if you have used it
than remove "the" from stopwords.txt
```